# How to avoid `Unnamed` columns during read.csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, glob

I have 20-30 csv files to be read.

So, I try the below code

```
pat_dir = ['file*.csv']
files_grabbed = []
for files in pat_dir:
    files_grabbed.extend(glob.glob(files))
for f in files_grabbed:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=",",low_memory=False)
    print(f)
    print(df.columns)
```

And printing them gives an output like below

```
file1.csv
Index(['Date', 'Code', 'Test', 'value', 'unit', 'TextualResults',
       'subject_id', 'class_id', 'Unnamed: 8',
       'Unnamed: 9', 'Unnamed: 10', 'Unnamed: 11', 'Unnamed: 12',
       'Unnamed: 13', 'Unnamed: 14', 'Unnamed: 15', 'Unnamed: 16',
       'Unnamed: 17', 'Unnamed: 18', 'Unnamed: 19', 'Unnamed: 20',
       'Unnamed: 21', 'Unnamed: 22', 'Unnamed: 23', 'Unnamed: 24',
       'Unnamed: 25', 'Unnamed: 26', 'Unnamed: 27', 'Unnamed: 28',
       'Unnamed: 29', 'Unnamed: 30', 'Unnamed: 31', 'Unnamed: 32',
       'Unnamed: 33', 'Unnamed: 34', 'Unnamed: 35', 'Unnamed: 36',
       'Unnamed: 37', 'Unnamed: 38', 'Unnamed: 39', 'Unnamed: 40',
       'Unnamed: 41', 'Unnamed: 42', 'Unnamed: 43', 'Unnamed: 44',
       'Unnamed: 45', 'Unnamed: 46', 'Unnamed: 47', 'Unnamed: 48',
       'Unnamed: 49', 'Unnamed: 50'],
```

While I can avoid the `unnamed` columns after read.csv using below code

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```

How can I avoid reading those `unnamed` column during `read.csv` operation?

Please note that I don't know the column names before hand. So, I can't define `column names` to read.csv. because each file can have different column names

So, is there any way to  drop them during read.csv operation because I have 30 files, and this causes issues during `glob` operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to remove `Unnamed` columns during reading a `csv` file?

Pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method accepts an optional keyword argument called `usecols` which is used select a subset of columns from a csv file. The interesting thing about this argument is that it can accept a **callable function**, this **callable function** is then evaluated against the column names and return only the column names where the callable function evaluates to `True`.

Here is how you can pass the callable function in your example to prevent the `Unnamed` columns from being read in first place.

```
for file in files_grabbed:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False, 
                     usecols=lambda c: not c.startswith('Unnamed:'))
```

Answer (score 2):

> pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).