# Python Pandas just read columns with names using lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Hi I know there is a way to load a csv or excel data and ignore empty column names using the lambda expression.

I used this expression before, but don't get it anymore. It was something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'my_file.csv'
with open(file) as w:
   df = pd.read_csv(w, usecols=lambda x: x not None)
```

So I get from a csv with this heading:

| Column A | Column B |  | Column D |  | Column G |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 | Cell 13 |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 | Cell 9 | Cell 10 | Cell 11 | Cell 12 | Cell 14 |

as a result:

| Column A | Column B | Column D | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 | Cell 10 | Cell 12 |

instead of

| Column A | Column B | Unnamed: 2 | Column D | Unnamed: 4 | Column G | Unnamed: 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 | Cell 13 |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 | Cell 9 | Cell 10 | Cell 11 | Cell 12 | Cell 14 |

I don't know the expression or the accurate way to deny it in my lambda expression.

I know there is a way to read a csv this way, and I don't want to use every used header in a list for usecols since the list would be very long.

Already thank you for your help.

baim

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need a file handle to read with `pd.read_csv`, just giving it the path to the file is enough.

Comment: May be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426042/how-to-avoid-unnamed-columns-during-read-csv-using-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid \`Unnamed\` columns during read.csv using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426042/how-to-avoid-unnamed-columns-during-read-csv-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas actually reads columns without a header already replaced by "Unnamed: #". You can check this by running

```py
pd.read_csv(w, usecols=lambda x: print(x))
```

So what you might want to do to remove these columns, is instead filter out the ones starting with "Unnamed"

```py
df = pd.read_csv(w, usecols=lambda x: not x.startswith("Unnamed"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works, but I was actually looking for another solution.

I think I used it two years ago somehow with np.nan, None pd.na or something like this.